# Using image in angular

Tags: css, angular

I have images stored in images folder inside assets folder

```
app 
  -app.component.css
assets
  -images
     -some-image.png
```

I'm trying to get the image in css inside background-image, but I think I have path related issues, since I can't seem to bring the image.

```
background-image:  url(../../../assets/images/some-image.png) no-repeat center top;
```

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which file has that css ? app.component.css ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try adding the style as following with a width and height. Also, isolate the background-repeat and background-position. It'd work.

```
  background-image:  url(../assets/images/some-image.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center-top;
  width: 100%; // any width
  height: 230px; // any height
```

To make it look better you can add,

```
background-size: contain;
```

**UPDATE:**

The reason that the image doesn't show up without width and height,
As default div is given a height of 0 since there are no inner elements.
But, it has a default width of 100% already.
Therefore, when we add an image using CSS background image property, we've to add the height attribute.

Comment: background-image value, I got as "invalid property value". So there is no image.

Comment: Try isolating the background-repeat, background-position. That's the reason for the error.

Answer (score 3):

It should be just,

```
background-image:  url(../assets/images/some-image.png) no-repeat center top;
```

Comment: .imgTest[_ngcontent-c0] {
  background-image: url(some-image.96d4b0ed5e559216f205.png) no-repeat center top; } //invalid property value.  This is what I got. "imgTest" is the class I have given to div.

Answer (score 2):

I just this should work just fine

```
background-image: url("../src/assets/images/some-image.png");
```

Answer (score 1):

Relative paths (in general) in CSS and HTML

**CSS**

```
background-image:  url(/assets/images/some-image.png) no-repeat center top;
```

**HTML:**

```
<img src="assets/images/some-image.png">
```

Answer (score 0):

you could not set `no-repeat` to `background-image`
It should be like code below:

```
background:  url(../assets/images/some-image.png) no-repeat center top;
```